# How far back does the 'recent' tag go?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

For the endpoint `/tags/tag-name/media/recent` how far back (how many days I guess) into the past can I retrieve instagram tags?

Also, is there any way to go farther back? I seem to only get about 10 days.

Comment: you can go way back to the first photo, try on http://gramfeed.com

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I am assuming they use the `/recent` tag because you can't go back to the first photo. However, the documentation does not give any advice as to how to get photos from all the way back.

Comment: the api response is ordered in reverse chronological order, it shows latest photos first, u have to scroll to go back to the first photo.

Comment: I see - so, I guess you still  use the recent tag and just scrolling all the way back is actually the way to do it.